# When would the compiler be conservative regarding pointer dereferencing optimization, if at all?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, optimization, dereference

So, I recently took an interest in how well the compiler (`gcc (GCC) 4.8.3` being the one in question) is in optimizing pointers and pointers.

Initially I created a simple integer and an integer pointer and realized
operations on it so I could print it out. As expected, all the operations
that were hard coded were optmized, through dereferenced pointer or not.

```
call    __main
leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
movl    $1, %edx
call    printf
```

And even after creating a function that takes in an int pointer,
dereferences it and changes it it still was perfectly optmized.

```
call    __main
leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
movl    $-1, %edx
call    printf
```

Now, when I treated my pointer as a void and made changes
by casting it to char and dereferencing it, it actually still optmized
perfectly (an 'extra' mov call since I initially treated it as an 8 byte
value, and then as a 1 byte value for pointer dereferencing)

```
call    __main
movl    $4, 44(%rsp)
movb    $2, 44(%rsp)
leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
movl    44(%rsp), %eax
leal    1(%rax), %edx
call    printf
```

So onto my question(s):

1. How consistent is compiler optimization regarding pointer dereferencing? What would be some cases where it would chose to be conservative?
2. If all of my pointers in a project were declared with the restrict keyword, could I trust it would be as well optimized as if 'no pointers were being used at all'?

(assuming there are no `volatile` cases )

Ps¹.: I am aware the compiler generally does a good enough job, and that a
programmer worrying about aiding the compiler in minor optimizations is, in
general, unproductive (as so many point out in stackoverflow answers to
questions regarding optimization). Yet I still have curiosity regarding the matter.

Ps².: `gcc -O3 -S -c main.c` was the command used to generate the assembly code

**C Code:** (as requested)

1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a = 4;
    int *ap = &a;

    *ap = 0;
    a += 1;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int *p) {
    *p -= 2;
}

int main (void)
{
    int a = 4;
    int *ap = &a;

    *ap = 0;
    change(ap);
    a += 1;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

3:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(void *p) {
    *((char*)p) += 2;
}

int main (void)
{
    int a = 4;
    void *ap = (void*) &a;

    *((char*)(ap)) = 0;
    change(ap);
    a += 1;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `restrict` and `const` are guarantees from the programmer, not by the compiler. If you break the contract, do not be surprised to invoke UB

Comment: Why not also include the C code that got you the resulting assembly you posted?

Comment: @JimBuck I appended them into the question.

Answer (score 3):

LLVM and GCC both emit static-single-assigment form code as a part of optimization analysis.  One of the useful properties of SSA code is that precisely shows the flow of influence for assignment -- that is, it knows what assignments lead to other assignments and so can detect which values can influence all others.

The first influence chain looks something like

a<sub>1</sub> -> constant(0) -> ap -> a<sub>2</sub>

The second:
a<sub>1</sub> -> constant(0) - > ap -> p -> a<sub>2</sub>

The third being pretty similar to the second.  (Sorry, this notation is pretty much made-up but i hope it illustrates my point.)

Because it is fairly simple to prove that the influence of a on ap is deterministic, it will feel free to dereference 'early' and combine the instructions into one (though in the first two cases this isn't the most accurate statement since the constant overwrites the original reference and lets the compiler prove that the original assignment does not flow to the end of the code.

Causing the compiler to be more conservative about dereferencing would involve getting complicated enough to escape the compiler's understanding (difficult in a static program i think)  or more likely causing the compiler to invoke a phi function in the process of SSA (in laymen's terms, to cause the assignment to be influenced by multiple previous assignments) in a nondeterministic way.

The restrict keyword has the purpose of hinting to the compiler that two pointers are different.  This wouldn't restrict the use of dereference at runtime if the code which produced that pointer still had a nondeterministic source (for example, if runtime-created data influenced the choice of what pointer value was dereferenced- i think this could happen if a serialized pointer was sent into the program from an external source?)